# preserving url in ingress nginx

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to put an ingress nginx controller in-front of my service in K8S using https/TLS configuration.

My service is using the URL in order to perform some business logic (if url is x.com do this and if url is y.com do that ... ) so I must forward the host/url to the service.

when I previously used nginx the following configuration did the trick:

```
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $host
```

How can make sure using ingress nginx controller the service gets the original used url?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the url to the backend while preserving the browser url in nginx ingress.

Rewrite the path to the service while preserving the browser url with nginx ingress on kubernetes.

It will create a capture group and send it to the appropriate service. Here is an Ingress example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "rewrite"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - http: example.com
        paths: 
          - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: echo-svc
              servicePort: 80
```

This ingress will request example.com to be delivered to echo1-svc(service).

For more information follow this [doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).